# Arduino Uno - EEPROM locations not consistant

Tags: arduino

I was trying to write items to the EEPROM and later read them out. I was finding the reading back I was not getting the same as I put in at times. I narrow down to an example I can show you. Below I read into variables 2 address.

```
const int start_add_type = (EEPROM.length() - 10);
const int start_add_id = (EEPROM.length() - 4);
```

I then look at the value (via RS232)

```
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println(start_add_type);
Serial.println(start_add_id);
```

of them at the start of the setup() and see I get

```
 1014
 1020
```

I then look again at the end

```
Serial.println(start_add_type);
Serial.println(start_add_id);
```

and I get

```
1014
818
```

I cannot see why this should change. I did try calling them const e.g. const

```
const int start_add_type = (EEPROM.length() - 10);
const int start_add_id = (EEPROM.length() - 4);
```

but this gave the same result. So here I sit very puzzled at what I must have missed. Anyone got any idea?

```
#include "EEPROM.h"


int start_add_type = (EEPROM.length() - 10);
int start_add_id = (EEPROM.length() - 4);
char ID[7] = "ENCPG2";
char Stored_ID[5];
char Input[10];
//String Type;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println(start_add_type);
  Serial.println(start_add_id);

 // start_add = (EEPROM.length() - 10);                      // use this method to be PCB independent.


  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
    Stored_ID[i] = EEPROM.read(start_add_type + i);             // Read the ID into the EEPROM. 
  }

  if (Stored_ID != ID)                                    // Check if the one we have got is the same as the one in this code ID[7]
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
      EEPROM.write(start_add_type + i, ID[i]);                 // Write     the ID into the EEPROM.
    }
  }
Serial.println(start_add_type);
Serial.println(start_add_id);
}


void loop()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your memory in this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    Stored_ID[i] = EEPROM.read(start_add_type + i);  
}
```

Stored_ID array is 5 bytes long, so writing to Stored_ID[5] will rewrite also the *start_add_id* variable, thus the weird value 818, which equals to 0x0332  HEX and 0x32 is the '2' character of your ID

For fixing this issue, declare Stored_ID in this way:

```
char Stored_ID[6];
```

Answer (score 0):

> if (Stored_ID != ID)

This is nonsense: You compare two different addresses, which are never equal. If you want to compare the content, you should do it in a loop. (e.g. directly when reading the EEPROM value into Stored_ID[i] )

Alternatively, Stored_ID could be a 0-terminated text as well and you might use
    if (strcmp(Stored_ID, ID) != 0)